# IE6 background-position(?) issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, background-image, background-position

I apply to **stackoverflow** as my last resort.
I got this ie6 bug while using the image at the background of the link.
It seems that ie6 scrolls the background. How can I avoid it?

At some width it shows like this:
[alt text http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/8849/badie1.png](http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/8849/badie1.png)

And at some other it shows like that:
[alt text http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/8180/badie2.png](http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/8180/badie2.png)

IE7 & FF show this just like I expect:
[alt text http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/2296/goodie.png](http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/2296/goodie.png)

The links are placed inside the div which is floating to the right.

```
<a href="/tr" class="menuLink" style="background-image:url(/img/tr.png);">TR</a>
<a href="/eng" class="menuLink" style="background-image:url(/img/eng.png); margin-right:30px;">ENG</a>
<a href="/logout" class="menuLink" style="background-image:url(/img/logout.png);"><?=$ui["exit"];?></a>

   .menuLink {
     font-family:"Tahoma";
     font-size:11px;
     color:#003300;
     text-decoration:underline;
     font-weight: bold;
     background-position:0% 50%;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
     .menuLink:hover {
     font-size:11px;
     color:#047307;
     text-decoration:underline;
     font-weight: bold;
     }
```

Any hints how can I avoid this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594870/fix-for-background-position-in-ie

Comment: Try adding "`zoom: 1`" to the style of the elements - hasLayout in IE can cause some strange bugs http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html. I haven't tried it, but this is one of the first things I try when debugging this kind of stuff as it often changes the way the background's rendered

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself and I found that using `overflow:hidden` on the element with the background image solved a lot of my IE6 problems (though not all).

Answer (score 1):

I would find a solution that works for IE6 and use [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85,loband).aspx) to filter out the other proper versions for IE7, FF, etc. I would also avoid using percents in the `background-position` for IE6 ([reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background/background_try.html)).

Comment: I tried to use <code>background-position:center left;</code> instead. It shows the same. So what exatly should I comment conditionally...

Comment: Try using a pixel value since everything you are dealing with are pixels.

Comment: I would keep hacking away. Once you get the right combination of styles package them up and use the conditional comments to override anything.

Answer (score 1):

As advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594870#595598) to [a somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594870), I'd recommend using `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` instead of `background-position` for IE (pre-IE8).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use background-position with any* ie6 .png fixes the solution is to make the image a gif or a 8-bit png.

*None that I use/tried

Comment: http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/ - Keeps background positions. It's the best PNG Fix IMO. But I would hazard a guess the PNG Fix is killing the background position also.

Comment: @MiG I had used the htc file fix [link](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) which didn't keep background positions. The DD_belatedPNG keeps.

Comment: I was able to get my 32-bit PNG to line up perfectly using overflow:hidden as recommended above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` in your element with background images and `background-positioning` -- in IE6 you can change your `padding-top: 16px;` to `margin-top: 16px;` and it fixes the problem.

It doesn't push other elements away and doubles the padding anymore.
Otherwise, in IE7 and IE8 the padding attribute works.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
background-position:0% 50%;
```

to

```
background-position:50% 50%;
```

and add

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This will center the image horizontially as well as vertically and stop the image from tiling.

Comment: If I do this, my image goes behind text :( And centers there, I need the images before the text...