# Receiving null on IE8/IE7 Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm not an expert in JavaScript but i have a simple function and is working correctly in all browsers except IE8 and 7

```
function setSelected() {
    var backgroundPos = $('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('backgroundPosition').split("");
    var xPos = backgroundPos[0];
    var yPos = '-100px';
    var toSet = xPos + ' ' + yPos;
    $('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('backgroundPosition', toSet);
    $('div.eventJumpToContainer span.jumpDate').not('.selected').each(function () {
        var backgroundPos = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
        var xPos = backgroundPos[0];
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', xPos + ' top');
    });
}
```

When stepping through this code in IE9:

```
$('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('backgroundPosition') = ‘3600px 0%’
```

But in IE8, this expression is null.

I've try a lot of things but i can't get it ! Thanks in advance

Comment: `backgroundposition`? You mean `background-position`, right?

Comment: Actually, IE does'nt understand the getter for background-position property, it does however support background-position-x/y ? See this SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594870/fix-for-background-position-in-ie

Comment: @PranavKapoor hyphenated CSS properties are translated to camel casing in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the javascript syntax for background position in the jQuery css function.

Example:

```
object.style.backgroundPosition="center"
```

In CSS the property is actually `'background-position'`

Try this:

```
$('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('background-position') = ‘3600px 0%’
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to use the `-ms-background-position-x -ms-background-position-y` properties.

Comment: I fixed !! :) ! i saw the post that @adeneo mention and i used 
'if (navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer')
   {
    var backgroundPos =    $('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('backgroundPositionX') + " " + var backgroundPos = $('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('backgroundPositionY');
   }
   else
   {
    var backgroundPos = $('div.eventJumpToContainer').find('.selected').css('background-position');

Comment: Good to hear! Glad I could help